# print a pdf file in python

Tags: python, linux

I want to print a pdf file in python. My code is as below:

```
def printing_reports():
 import os
fp = open("/path-to-file/path.txt",'r')
for line in fp:
    os.system('lp -d HPLaserJ %s' % (str(line)))
```

I am on Fedora 20. `path.txt` is a file that contain path to the pdf file like '/home/user/a.pdf'
When I run the code it says no such file or directory.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the complete backtrace you receive.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: `'%s' % 'foo'` is the same as `'%s' % ('foo',)`. (Though always supplying a tuple as you suggest is conceptually cleaner.)

Comment: The output is:`" - No such file or directory"/home/user/serial_num.txt`. /home/user/serial_num.txt is the path.txt content. when I put the serial_num.txt directly like this:` os.system('lp -d HPLaserJ /home/user/serial_num.txt')`, it print the file content successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code may help:

```
import os

def printing_reports():
  fp = open("/path-to-file/path.txt",'r')
  for line in fp:
      os.system('lp -d HPLaserJ {0}'.format(line.strip()))

 printing_reports()
```

Make sure the file in every line exists.

Comment: I get this error when I tried this solution: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 28: invalid start byte

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but as I needed a an answer of how to print a pdf file from python, I found [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98076/print-pdf-files-using-python-code) more profound:

```
import cups
conn = cups.Connection()
printers = conn.getPrinters()
printer_name = printers.keys()[0]
ppd_options = {}
cups_job_id = conn.printFile(printer_name,'/path/to/a.pdf',"Title printjob", ppd_connection_options)
```

It uses the [pycups](https://pypi.org/project/pycups/) module, which needs CUPS >= 1.7 installed on your system (according to their GitHub page)

The ppd_options dictionary might just be empty. ([PPD - Postscript Printer Driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_Printer_Description))